# Log4j2 disable console on production

Tags: log4j2, appender

I'm developing a Web app and I'm using log4j2. In developing mode, I'm logging using RollingFile and Console appenders.

Everything is working properly, but I'd want to disable the Console appender when my project will be released and it will be in production mode. 
Here's a slice of my log4j2.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="PropertiesConfig" packages="com.project.application">

    <!-- PROPERTIES -->
    <Properties>
        <Property name="webName">Project</Property> 
        <Property name="logBaseDir">${sys:catalina.base}/logs/</Property>
        <Property name="consolePattern">%highlight{[%-5level] [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS}] [%c{1}] - %msg%n}</Property>
        <Property name="rollingFilePattern">[%-5level] [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS}] [%c{1}] - %msg%n</Property>
    </Properties>

    <!-- APPENDERS -->
    <Appenders>
        <!-- Console -->
        <Console name="Console" 
                 target="SYSTEM_OUT"
                 immediateFlush="true">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>${consolePattern}</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>

        <!-- RollingFile -->
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" 
                     fileName="${sys:logBaseDir}${webName}/${webName}.log"
                     filePattern="${sys:logBaseDir}${webName}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
                     immediateFlush="true">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>${rollingFilePattern}</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>

    <!-- LOGGERS -->
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.project.application" additivity="true" level="warn">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
        </Logger>

        <Root level="info"> <!-- @TODO disable in production -->
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />                
        </Root>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [filter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/filters.html), e.g. `ThreadContextMapFilter`:

```xml
<Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT" immediateFlush="true">
  <ThreadContextMapFilter onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL">
    <KeyValuePair key="is-production" value="1"/><!-- skip on production -->
  </ThreadContextMapFilter>
  <PatternLayout>
    <pattern>${consolePattern}</pattern>
  </PatternLayout>
</Console>
```

The initialization of the `ThreadContext` entry can be perfomed in a `ServletContextListener`, e.g.:

```java
@WebListener
public class Log4jThreadContextInitializer implements ServletContextListener {

  @Override
  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    String isProduction = isProduction() ? "1" : "0";
    sce.getServletContext().log("Setting 'is-production' flag for Log4j to " + isProduction);
    org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContext.put("is-production", isProduction);
  }

  private boolean isProduction() {
    // TODO: production detection
  }

  @Override
  public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Some questions: can I set the value in the xml as "1" or "0" directly and nothing else? Why the initialization in the ServletContextListener?

Comment: @Ommadawn But if you were to set the value in the XML (I don't even know if it's at all possible), how would you detect whether it *is* production or not? Perhaps, you'd need a different `log4j2.xml` for production then. Note that the code in `log4j2.xml` that I posted does *not* set anything - it only *tests* if the value is set to `"1"` or not.

Comment: I just would wanted a value that if it was set as 1, it disable the console output print

Comment: @Ommadawn I'm afraid I don't understand. In the answer, I've shown how it can be done. If something's unclear, please be more specific about what exactly it is that you expect.

Comment: Sorry, @Tomasz Linkowski, I'm not native english speaker. I mean... If I have set "is-production" as "1", will automatically the logger DON'T log into console?

Comment: @Ommadawn Yes, if you set `is-production` to `1` in `ThreadContext`, Log4j2 will skip the console appender (because the `ThreadContextMapFilter` is configured as `onMatch="DENY"`, meaning it skips the appender if the condition matches).

Answer (score 1):

[Spring-lookup](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html#SpringLookup) made my life easier. My appender is like this:

```
<Appenders>
    <Console name="console-local" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{2}:%L - %msg%n" />
    </Console>
</Appenders>
```

I have added a property like this:

```
<Properties>
    <Property name="console-appender">console-${spring:profiles.active}</Property>
</Properties>
```

And the logger is like this:

```
<Loggers>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="${console-appender}"/>
    </root>
</Loggers>
```

If my active profile is **local**, thus *console-appender* will be set to *console-local*, and the log will be shown in the **console**, as **ref** will find *console-local*.

Again, suppose, my active profile is **prod**, then *console-appender* will be set to *console-prod*, and the log will not be shown in the **console**, as **ref** will not find *console-prod*. Because Console's appender name is still *console-local*.

**My log4j version is 2.14.1**